# Angular rxjs interval not subscribing

Tags: angular, rxjs, intervals, subscription

I have this piece of code:

```
interval(180000).pipe(takeUntil(this._unsub$)).subscribe(() => myFunc())
```

_unsub$ is a subject that is fired in ngOnDestroy method.
My problem is that myFunc never get executed.

The same piece of code in another component works. I can't understand why.

```
timer(0, 180000).pipe(takeUntil(this._unsub$)).subscribe(() => myFunc())
```

works.
My problem with timer is that sometimes calls the function even if I call

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   this._unsub$.next();
   this._unsub$.complete();
}
```

Any guess why this happens?

Comment: Are you saying `myFunc` inside `interval()` doesn't fire at all, even after waiting the 3 minute period?

Comment: exactly, that's my issue. I always use interval this way and it works all the time

Comment: Have you tried logging out when `_unsub$` emits to ensure it isn’t causing your subscription to end earlier than expected?

Answer (score 1):

Both interval and timer are cold observables, and observables are lazy (unlike promises) so your timer isn't called until you subscribe and a new timer is created when you subscribe.

These two settups are the same:

```js
const firstFunc = () => ...
const secondFunc = () => ...
const interval1$ = interval(180000).pipe(takeUntil(this._unsub$));
const interval2$ = interval(180000).pipe(takeUntil(this._unsub$));
interval1$.subscribe(firstFunc);
interval2$.subscribe(secondFunc);
```

```js
const firstFunc = () => ...
const secondFunc = () => ...
const interval$ = interval(180000).pipe(takeUntil(this._unsub$));
interval$.subscribe(firstFunc);
interval$.subscribe(secondFunc);
```

So you have to consider when `.subscribe` is called. That's my best guess to explain the difference between very similar code in different components. If `this._unsub$.next();` is called a moment before subscribing to your timer, then 180seconds later, the timer will still fire as it never received the `_unsub$` signal.

Comment: I subscribe to observable rightaway in ngOnInit function. I call _unsub$.next() in ngOnDestroy. So timer fires event even after _unsub$.next() because it has been scheduled but won't fire the subsequent one? at the moment the only way i got my code to work is using js setInterval() and closeIntervals in ngOnDestroy because interval does not fire its function